# MVC selecting only specified ids from 2 controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am new to MVC and C# and have a question. I have a MVC project and using Entity Framework I have created my models from the Database.
I have created a property controller with a details view I have also set up a samples controller and views. The sample and property table are linked by the Property Id in the database.
On the details page of the property I have set up a button that opens up the Samples index page but I want it to just show the samples that are linked with the property selected. How do I select just the samples with the selected Property Id?

Below is the button I created on the property details page

```
<input type="button" value="Samples Summary" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Index", "Sample") + "'");" />
```

Here is my Sample controller for index

```
  public ActionResult Index(int? pageNumber)
        {
            var samples = db.Samples.Include(s => s.Property).
            var records = db.Samples.AsQueryable();


            return View(records.OrderBy(i => i.Id).ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 50));
        }
```

Hopefully this makes sense and I appreciate any help you guys can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the selected `PropertyId` to your Index action. I am assuming the "Property" page has the current ID in its ViewModel.

```
<input type="button" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Index", "Sample", new { propertyId = Model.PropertyId }) + "'");" />
```

Then use the passed `PropertyId` to filter the samples using a [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations#filtering) clause.

```
public ActionResult Index(int propertyId, int? pageNumber) {
     var samples = db.Samples
         .Include(s => s.Property)
         .Where(s => s.Property.Id == propertyId);

     // don't know why are you retrieving all samples again into "records"
     // in the code you have shown?

     return View(samples.OrderBy(i => i.Id).ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 50));
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. This has worked a treat.